# check if grafana agent operator is up and running

Tags: grafana, metrics, promql

I have a grafana agent operator and I was trying to create some metrics to monitor if it's up.
If I had a simple grafana agent process I would just use something along the lines of `absent(up{instance="1.2.3.4:8000"} == 1` but with the Grafana Agent operator the components are dynamic.
I don't see issues with monitoring the metrics part. For example, if the `grafana-agent-0` stateful set for metrics goes down and a new pod is built the name would be the same.
But for logs, the Grafana Agent operator runs a pod (daemon set) for every node with a different name each time.

In the log case if a pod `grafana-agent-log-vsq5r` goes down or a new node is added to the cluster I would have a new pod to monitor with a different name which would create some problems in being able to monitor the changes in the cluster. Anyone that already had this issue or that knows some good way of tackling the issue?

Answer (score 0):

I would like to suggest using [Labels in Grafana Alerting](https://grafana.com/docs/grafana/latest/alerting/fundamentals/annotation-label/how-to-use-labels/#labels-in-grafana-alerting)

[image]